# Print an string in an 2d array c++

Tags: c++

I want to ask how can I print the word Chessmaster in 2d array randomly each letter of the word? I tried with srand but I don't how to combine it with characters. Can someone help me with is code. Also, can I create random letters in a 2d array without rand ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const int MAX = 11;

using namespace std;

void printwo()
{
    char word[MAX] = {'c', 'h', 'e', 's', 's', 'm', 'a', 's', 't', 'e', 'r'};
    int c, i, n, letters;

    cout << "I will print this word " << word << " sepereate" << endl;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout << "Print a random letter["
                 << "][" << word[i] << "]"
                 << "["
                 << "]";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int c;

    cout << "Hello user press  _1_ to continue" << endl;
    cin >> c;

    if (c == 1)
    {
        printwo();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Bye";
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a valid output?

Comment: So is the 2d array meant to be 7 by 2?

Comment: May letters be repeated? Should they be filled with (random-positioned) spaces?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for.  Is https://onlinegdb.com/Syh5NgODU the sort of thing or are you looking for something else?

Comment: If you want really want to use rand you could https://onlinegdb.com/SkGt5xdP8 but rand() doesn't produce a uniform distribution (some numbers are more likely than others)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const int MAX = 11;

using namespace std;

// Generate a random number between min and max (inclusive)
// Assumes std::srand() has already been called
// Assumes max - min <= RAND_MAX
int getRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    static constexpr double fraction { 1.0 / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) };  // static used for efficiency, so we only calculate this value once
    // evenly distribute the random number across our range
    return min + static_cast<int>((max - min + 1) * (std::rand() * fraction));
}

void printwo()
{
    char word[MAX+1] = {"chessmaster"}; //If you are using C-style strings then you should declare +1 space
    //int c, i, n, letters; not needed

    cout << "I will print this word " << word << " sepereate" << endl;

    //srand only gives a seed to yout tand function, you need to call std::rand() to get a random integer
    //use the function getRandomNumber above that is based on rand() and gives you the possibility to select range
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout << "Print a random letter["
                 << "][" << word[getRandomNumber(0,10)] << "]" 
                 << "["
                 << "]";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{        
    int c;
    cout << "Hello user press  _1_ to continue" << endl;
    cin >> c;

    if (c == 1)
    {
        printwo();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Bye";
        //exit(0); exit here not needed
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote some comments.. please read them and ask me if you don't get something. I would suggest reading about C-style strings and rand() here:
    Rand() - https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/59-random-number-generation/
    C-style strings(basically arrays of char) - https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/66-c-style-strings/

Comment: Thank for the help but I want to ask something the compiler shows me some errors but somehow the code runs my main question is can  I print the word Chessmaster in different positions for example [ ] [s ] [ ]                                                                                                                                                      
                                  [ ]  [ ]  [h  ] bun not in the left side only in the 2 others array thank you in advance

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Please, be more specific about what you want to print!

Comment: Sorry I will try to explain better I want to print the word Chessmaster randomly in array at each line but the first array in each line I want to be always empty also I posted a picture down in the comments to help you thank you in advance.